# Why are there no amateur allocations in the LF and VLF spectrum?

Tags: united-states, frequency, vlf

Amateur radio enthusiasts have slices of spectrum at every magnitude of spectrum MF and above, but in the US none are below MF.

Why are there no spectrum allocations below 160M?

Comment: While not a full answer as to why we don't have a spectrum allocation, here is some information in regards to LF and amateur radio operations. I remember reading of LF experimenters and the hopes to eventually get an allocation. http://www.arrl.org/lf-low-frequency

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2200-meter_band

Comment: There is allocation below 10khz, some experiments i'm working on is using huge loops on the ground and ground rods for communication, and I have already had luck up to TWO WHOLE CITY BLOCKS!!!! Using no modulation whatsoever, just audio from a 100Watt HI-FI home stereo system

Comment: @Optionparty https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2200-meter_band#United_States specifically states that there is currently no such allocation in the US, while the question is tagged `united-states`.

Comment: The 136 kc band was allocated with the CB 28 mc band long ago. As an "Experimental" band. Not specifically for Ham radio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [US allocation of frequencies](http://www.ntia.doc.gov/files/ntia/publications/2003-allochrt.pdf) for the source data for some of this.

Right now, the current users of VLF/LF are either maritime mobile, radio navigation, time frequencies, or aeronautical use. There are a few stations that have experimental privileges, as [ARRL mentions](http://www.arrl.org/lf-low-frequency). The bandwidth for these bands drops dramatically, often only a few kilohertz.

As [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2200-meter_band) mentions, the reason why the 2200 band isn't available in the United states is:

> On May 14, 2003, however, the FCC declined to grant these privileges
>   citing concerns over potential interference with power line
>   communications (PLC) systems operating unlicensed under Part 15 used
>   by electrical utilities to control the power grid. But the FCC added
>   that amateurs wishing to experiment with 136 kHz communications may
>   apply for a Part 5 Experimental License or operate under Part 15
>   regulations for this part of the electromagnetic spectrum.

See also the [FCC ruling directly](http://hraunfoss.fcc.gov/edocs_public/attachmatch/FCC-03-105A1.pdf), which specifically states:

> While we agree that amateur experimentation in the 135.7-137.8 kHz and
>   160-190 kHz portions of the LF spectrum could serve to increase the
>   pool of individuals having knowledge of LF transmissions, we conclude
>   that such operations would pose the potential for harmful interference
>   to systems protecting and controlling the national power grid.